# installing ubuntu in offline mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, wubi

I have made a dual boot of fedora 16 and windows 7. I wanted to make a triple boot by installing *ubuntu 11* which i just downloaded *(iso file 695 MB)* from their official website. Can i install it in offline mode using *Wubi* ? If not is there any other way out else than DVD or USB stick .

Is there anything extra i need to do to install ubuntu when i already have a dual boot with Win7 and fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine installing Ubuntu offline. You wont be able to download security updates, so I suggest you update the system as soon as you connect to the internet.

There is nothing special that you have to do installing Ubuntu when you already have Windows and Fedora. Many multi-booting users like to use a partition separate from their OS installations  to store their files so that they can be accesses from any OS, so you could look into that if you don't mind repartitioning the drive.